# VBA Disable _Exit event when user push a command button

Tags: vba

I've a Userform with few textbox & combobox. In order to check data entry i've activate the _exit(By...)  private sub, for each elements in the userform.
So when "element" lost the focus the sub is executed.
Btw, if user wants to skip the data entry, pushing another CommandButton, i'd like to skip all _exit events...how i can do.
It's possible to check which Command button has been pressed before the _exit event?

Thansk in advance.

Comment: Set a module level variable e.g. flag and set its value to true when the skip button is pressed. Then simply check the flag's value before exiting.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, but problem is more complex. When Command Button is pressed, first step of VBA is to execute _EXIT sub, due to lost focus of the related textbox,